# Choice of Outcomes in Experiments

Tags: regression, econometrics, experiment-design

Suppose I design an experiment. I can choose between two types of outcomes:

(i) continious outcome $Y$, which is restricted to the interval $0\leq Y \leq 1$

(ii) quasi-continious outcome $Y$, which takes the values: $0.1, 0.2,...,1$

Which one should I choose given that I want to maximize statistical power of the following regression (OLS):

$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1T$.

$T$ is a binary treatment indicator.

Answer (score 1):

I'd always choose the more granular option (i), all else being equal.

Then, maybe try transforming your $Y$ in to $Y^*$ before OLS estimation using the inverse CDF of an appropriate distribution. Once you get your $\hat{Y}^*,$ put it through the CDF to get $\hat{Y}$ and back into the 0 to 1 interval.

Caution should be used, however, since it is probably true in your case that $E[f(Y)]\neq f(E[Y])$